# Replacing present values (all except NA/NaN) in pandas data frame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a `fillna` method for filling missing values, but is there a method for replacing all the actual values with a given value.

For example:

```
      c
  0  NA/NaN
  1  2.0
  2  NA/NaN
  3  6.0
  4  8.0
  5  NA/NaN
  6  12.0
```

For every data point, I would like to mark it with 'v' meaning that it contains a valid value:

```
      c
  0   NA/NaN
  1  'v'
  2   NA/NaN
  3  'v'
  4  'v'
  5   NA/NaN
  6  'v'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Is there a specific reason why you want to overwrite the existing value, instead of keeping a separate series or column of `validity`?
- And using a custom marker instead of a `boolean` value is also an extra complexity.

Further down in your code it would be easier to simply us

```
valid = df['c'].notnull()
```

if you really want to overwrite it with a marker string:

```
df.loc[df['c'].notnull(), 'c'] = 'v'
```

Comment: Yes, I have a few categories to construct based on if the value in question is a raw data, or calculated data (and what kind of calculation method was used). I agree that a boolean marker would be a much better approach, but it does not fulfil my requirements.

Comment: you can use a boolean marker  or separate series during the calculations, but replace it with the markers during the reporting

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
df.loc[~df['c'].isnull()] = "'v'"
```